# how to fix my git push error? did I screw it up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

Up to this point, I had very few problems deploying my app. 
However, after a deployment tonight, I got an unfixable app error. So I did a rollback from **v7** back to **v4** from a week ago. The app worked again but I decided to try to "git push heroku master -f" **v5** which I didn't think would have the app error found on **v7**. Unfortunately, **v5** also gave me the same error.

Afterwards, I tried a rollback to a working version **v4** but it still gave me an error. I tried another rollback but it still gave me an app error. I then tried to "git push heroku master -f" **v4** (which I know works) from my local hard drive but it now says "Everything up-to-date".

What do I do from here? my app is not working on heroku and I can't do any rollback or even push a version that works now. How can I get it working? I want to redeploy **v4** which is a working version and rewrite the code piece by piece to get back to the current level.

Everything works fine when in development environment and viewing in `rails server`
But, this is the error that I get when running `rails server -e production`

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-09 02:09:49 -0700
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:19:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `signed_in?'
  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:3:in `home'




Started GET "/favicon.ico" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-09 02:09:49 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `c
all'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `ca
ll'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `
call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `servi
ce'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in
start_thread'
```

However, the error that I get after deployment using `heroku logs` is related to a Rails `superclass mismatch error` for a controller

Comment: First post your heroku error. You can see errors with `heroku logs` command.

Comment: We tried to solve it and asked various people but we have no idea how to solve it. The error is related to a `superclass mismatch` for a class in a rails controller. We're trying to just get the working version up and rewrite the code piece by piece. How can I deploy v4 using `git push heroku master -f`  when it says "Everything up-to-date". The later version has the app error

Comment: just posted up the error off `rails server -e production`

Comment: This is a completely trivial error and would not cause an app to not work. What is the _real_ error?

Answer (score 0):

Part of your log is saying you don't have table `users`.

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
>   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:19:in `current_user'
>
>   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in`signed_in?'
>   app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:3:in `home'

Did you applied migration? If not, try with:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You two unrelated issues here.  `rails server -e production` isn't working because you need to run your migrations against the production version of your local database, so do this: `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

You Heroku issue is going to unrelated to that.  You will need to post your Heroku logs from `heroku logs` for anyone to help you with that.

Also, forcing a git push to Heroku is not how you rollback a release.  You do it like this: `heroku releases:rollback [RELEASE]`